# Jenkinsfile find files in S3 with s3FindFiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I wan to use `s3FindFiles` in Jenkinsfile (pipeline) to search for file in S3 bucket. I tried to use it it following way

```
        steps {
            withCredentials([[
                $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-for-aws',accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
            ]]) {
                    s3FindFiles(bucket:'my-bucket', path:'firmwares/', glob:'gwsw_*')
                }
        }
```

which prints

```
      Searching s3://my-bucket/firmwares/ for glob:'gwsw_*' 
      Search complete
```

How do I get name of the files from it ?

As per [s3FindFiles](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#s3findfiles) it return `name`, so I tried

```
    steps {
                withCredentials([[
                    $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-for-aws',accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                ]]) {
                        files = s3FindFiles(bucket:'my-bucket', path:'firmwares/', glob:'gwsw_*')
                        echo files[0].name
                    }
            }
```

But got this error :

```
 WorkflowScript: 256: Expected a step @ line 256, column 19.
                   files = s3FindFiles(bucket:'my-bucket', path:"firmwares/", glob:'gwsw_*')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`s3FindFiles`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#s3findfiles-find-files-in-s3)

> return an array of FileWrapper instances with the following properties:
>
> - name: the filename portion of the path (for "path/to/my/file.ext",
>   this would be "file.ext")
> - path: the full path of the file, relative to
>   the path specified (for path="path/to/", this property of the file
>   "path/to/my/file.ext" would be "my/file.ext")
> - directory: true if this
>   is a directory; false otherwise length: the length of the file (this
>   is always "0" for directories)
> - lastModified: the last modification
>   timestamp, in milliseconds since the Unix epoch (this is always "0" for directories)

you can simply iterate over the returned array using either the properties above or the [dedicated methods](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-aws/de/taimos/pipeline/aws/FileWrapper.html#allclasses_navbar_top:%7E:text=Method%20Summary)

e.g: get file name

```
name_by_property = files[0].name   
name_by_method = files[0].getName()
```

if you are using `declarative pipeline` you'll need to wrap your code with `script` block:

```
steps {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-for-aws', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

            script{
              files = s3FindFiles(bucket:'my-bucket', path:'firmwares/', glob:'gwsw_*', onlyFiles: true)
              
              // get the first name
              println files[0].name

              // iterate over all files
              files.each { println "File name: ${it.name}, timestamp: ${it.lastModified}"}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Got WorkflowScript error, updated in my question.

Comment: @roy if you are using declarative pipeline, you'll need to wrap your code with `script` tag, i've update my answer, to contain the script tag
just: 
```script{
files = s3FindFiles(bucket:'my-bucket', path:'firmwares/', glob:'gwsw_*')
echo files[0].name
}```

Comment: @roy did this solution solved your issue?